# Object column containing strings retain string type after converting to categorical data type(Pandas Categorical)

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

In Pandas, I am trying to convert data of data type object containing string values into categorical data type. Even after converting and system showing that the data type is categorical, I am still able to perform string functions on it and `pd.api.types.is_string_dtype` is returning `True`. Due to this, when I am trying to fit a machine learning model for the data, it errors out.

Input:

```
df_tmp["UsageBand"] = df_tmp["UsageBand"].astype("category")
df_tmp["UsageBand"].dtypes,pd.api.types.is_string_dtype(df_tmp["UsageBand"])
```

Output: `(CategoricalDtype(categories=['High', 'Low', 'Medium'], ordered=True), **True**)`

Error seen when trying to fit model

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

~\machinelearning\sample-project\bulldozer-project\env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_forest.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    293         """
    294         # Validate or convert input data
--> 295         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse="csc", dtype=DTYPE)
    296         y = check_array(y, accept_sparse='csc', ensure_2d=False, dtype=None)
    297         if sample_weight is not None:

~\machinelearning\sample-project\bulldozer-project\env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    529                     array = array.astype(dtype, casting="unsafe", copy=False)
    530                 else:
--> 531                     array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    532             except ComplexWarning:
    533                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

~\machinelearning\sample-project\bulldozer-project\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     83 
     84     """
---> 85     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     86 
     87 

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Low'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of converting all the categorical content into numbers, I had only done this conversion on the null data causing the problem.

Wrong code:

```
for cols in df_tmp.columns:
    if not pd.api.types.is_numeric_dtype(df_tmp[cols]) and df_tmp[cols].isnull().sum() >0:
        df_tmp[cols+"_is_missing"] = df_tmp[cols].isnull()
        df_tmp[cols] = pd.Categorical(df_tmp[cols]).codes + 1
```

Correct Code:

```
for labels,content in df_tmp.items():
    if not pd.api.types.is_numeric_dtype(content):
        df_tmp[labels+"is_missing"] = pd.isnull(content)
        df_tmp[labels] = pd.Categorical(content).codes + 1
```